Removing Graphics, but not Sprites on C64
I am trying to remember that removing all graphic elements, but not sprites. The aim is to disable DMA and ease to open side borders etc...
As I remember it was an option at $D011, but it seems it doesnt.
Could be tricky, how to do that?

The trick is to continously modify the screen-size and scroll registers so that the scan position never matches the configured right border, nor the bottom border, nor the start of a scan line.  I'm posting as a comment rather than an answer because I'm pretty sure this question has been asked and answered elsewhere, but what you describe is doable.

I found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8231029/2007222 Thank you to all who give attention!

Opening the borders on the C64 is a timing exercise.  It is most difficult to do them all, and some recommend doing the top and bottom ones first.
I have linked a couple articles that describe how this is done.
It will also be different between NTSC and PAL machines.  The refresh rates are different, 50Hz vs 60hz for NTSC.
I am not going to comment on the specifics largely because I have not spent a ton of time on the C64 myself.
https://codebase64.org/doku.php?id=base:opening_up_the_borders_-_a_further_explanation
http://www.0xc64.com/2014/11/16/removing-the-upper-and-lower-borders/
